# why should use MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, rdbms

- In which types of projects, MongoDB is the best suited?
- Can we use MongoDB in large applications?
- Why Open Source CMS and framework doesn't have support for MongoDB?
- How it is different than other open source RDBMS like MySQL and PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2):

Mongo is NOT an RDBMS. Don't treat it like one and you'll avoid a lot of mistakes. This is why applications that require an RDBMS don't support Mongo.

MongoDB is well suited to applications where:

- The working set of documents (and their indexes) can be kept in RAM.
- Document sizes do not change much between creation and steady state.
- The schema needs to be flexible.

It can definitely be used in large applications, with the right engineering. It depends a lot on how the application plans to use Mongo, though. With sharding to spread write loads you can get to some very high throughputs.